# Bluetooth network loses connection and must be restarted every few minutes

Tags: bluetooth, internet-sharing

I use an iPad as Bluetooth hotspot and connect my Macbook to internet via the iPad's mobile network. However, every few minutes I have to restart Bluetooth on my computer because the connection seems to stall. The BT icon in the menu bar indicates that the connection is up but nothing loads. Restarting BT fixes this but it is very annoying to be interrupted like this.

Any ideas what might be wrong and how I can fix this?

Edit: The devices are next to each other. No WiFi, last time this happened I was in the middle of the forest.

Comment: What is the physical distance of the MacBook from the iPad and are there any walls or ceilings between them? [This page](https://www.sans.edu/cyber-research/security-laboratory/article/bluetooth) at SANS explains Bluetooth distance restrictions. From [this forum](https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1292958-bluetooth-power-class-of-ipad/) you can find out how to determine the BT device in the iPad itself and thence its maximum distance. Please edit your question to include the specific model of iPad you are using.

Comment: Please add to your OQ if you also have Wi-Fi used in the same environment (by you or your neighbors) and on which channels?